# upload submodule to ftp server using bitcucket pipeline

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines, git-ftp

Is there any way to upload git submodules to ftp server using bitbucket pipeline?
I'm able to upload main repo to ftp server but not it's sub module.

The code I have used is as follows:

```
# This is a sample build configuration for Other.
# Check our guides at https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/5Q4SMw for more examples.
# Only use spaces to indent your .yml configuration.
# -----
# You can specify a custom docker image from Docker Hub as your build environment.
# image: atlassian/default-image:latest

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - apt-get update
          - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
          - git submodule update --init --recursive
          - git ftp push --user $FTP_USERNAME --passwd $FTP_PASSWORD $FTP_SERVER
```

Comment: Does the command work on your computer? Did you `git ftp init` before this this script runs? What is the error message?

Comment: Did you find the answer to this?

@maikel there is no error locally because the files exist, the error is with Pipelines because the files do not exist as BitBucket treats submodules as a reference, so it treats it as an empty folder.

Comment: No brother. did not find any solution

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with this for the past 2 days here is the asnwer i came up with:

`pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
      script:
        - git submodule update --init --recursive
        - pipe: atlassian/ftp-deploy:0.3.7
          variables:
            USER: $FTP_username
            PASSWORD: $FTP_password
            SERVER: $FTP_server
            REMOTE_PATH: /path/where/to/put/on/remote/server
            EXTRA_ARGS: "--transfer-all" *optional`

hope it works for you